# Setting maxLength attribute on a formcontrol dynamically in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, form-control

I want to set the maxLength for an input element in Angular dynamically. Currently I am doing something like this:

```
<input type="text" [formControlName]="name"
    [maxlength]="attribute.attributeName === AttributeName.FIRST_NAME ? 15 : attribute.attributeName === AttributeName.LAST_NAME ? 20 : 255">
```

but, this is not efficient in my opinion. I have a another scenario where I would need to check the condition for at least 15 different scenarios then set the maxLength.

I was wondering if there's any way to dynamically set it in the typescript file using @ViewChild?

Answer (score 0):

try to grab following concept

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  maxLength: number = 20; //defult on load 1st

  updateMaxLengthDynm(newLength: number): void {
    this.maxLength = newLength; //change it as logic flow by call the function otherwise you can pass the function call 
     //or the logic directely to the oninit of course that req to implement onit in the class
  }
}
```

for the HTML

```
<input type="text" [maxLength]="maxLength">
<button (click)="updateMaxLengthDynm(25)">now press seting MaxLength to 25</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="text" [formControlName]="name" [maxlength]="getMaxLength(attribute.attributeName)">




// Inside your component class
getMaxLength(attributeName: AttributeName): number {
  switch (attributeName) {
    case AttributeName.FIRST_NAME:
      return 15;
    case AttributeName.LAST_NAME:
      return 20;
    // Add more cases for other scenarios as needed
    default:
      return 255; // Default maxLength
  }
}
```

Comment: Try **avoid** include functions in your .html. This makes that Angular execute several times the function. Angular need know what "variables" has changed to show the new values in .html. For this, Angular store the value of the "variable" and compare with the new value. When you write a function in .html, Angular must execute the function to know the new value